# How to multiply every other columns in multiple files

Tags: awk

all

I have three files like this: file1 file2 file3 and they have same number of rows and columns. Each file contains 72 columns (first two columns are the same, (2n+1)th columns are the same too),like

file1

```
20170101 1 1 1 2 2 3 3...  
20170101 2 1 2 2 4 3 4...
20170101 3 1 5 2 3 3 6 ...
```

file2

```
20170101 1 1 0 2 1 3 3...  
20170101 2 1 2 2 4 3 2...
20170101 3 1 3 2 4 3 1 ..
```

file3

```
20170101 1 1 2 2 3 3 0...  
20170101 2 1 1 2 4 3 2...
20170101 3 1 4 2 4 3 0 ..
```

Starting from column 4, I would like to multiply every other columns ,like col4,col6 ,col8,col10... The output should be

```
20170101 1 1 0 2 6 3 0...  
20170101 2 1 4 2 64 3 16...
20170101 3 1 60 2 48 3 0 ..
```

I tried this, but all the columns starting from col4 will be multiplied together.

```
paste file1 file2 file3| awk '{ for(i=3;i<=NF/2; i++) printf("%4.2E ", $i*$(i+NF/2)*$(i+NF))); printf("\n"); }'
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all input files have same number of lines:

```
$ awk '{getline a < "f2"; getline b < "f3"; split(a,s1); split(b,s2)}
       {for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=2) $i*=s1[i]*s2[i]; print}' f1
20170101 1 1 0 2 6 3 0
20170101 2 1 4 2 64 3 16
20170101 3 1 60 2 48 3 0
```

- `getline a < "f2"` gets one line from file2, saved in variable `a`
- `split(a,s1)` split the content in `a` (same as default input line splitting) and saved in variable `s1`
- `for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=2) $i*=s1[i]*s2[i]` required operation
- `print` print the modified input line - use formatting if needed
- See [AllAboutGetline](https://web.archive.org/web/20170524214527/http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) for getline caveats

Comment: Your solution is way better than mine +1! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you were using `paste` command I will use it in my answer, otherwise I would really recommend using the solution from Sundeep with the `getline`:

The following paste command will interleave the 3 files:

```
$ paste -d '\n' file1 file2 file3
20170101 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 
20170101 1 1 0 2 1 3 3  
20170101 1 1 2 2 3 3 0
20170101 2 1 2 2 4 3 4
20170101 2 1 2 2 4 3 2
20170101 2 1 1 2 4 3 2
20170101 3 1 5 2 3 3 6
20170101 3 1 3 2 4 3 1
20170101 3 1 4 2 4 3 0
```

You can after use `awk` on the output this output to generate the output you need to have:

```
$ paste -d '\n' file1 file2 file3 | awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=2)if(NR>1){a[i]*=$i;}else{a[i]=$i}if(NR%3==0){printf $1 OFS $2 OFS; for(i in a){printf $(i-1) OFS a[i] OFS;a[i]=1}printf ORS;}}'
20170101 1 1 0 2 6 3 0 
20170101 2 1 4 2 64 3 16 
20170101 3 1 60 2 48 3 0
```

**Explanations:**

```
{
    for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=2) #loop on all other columns 
        if(NR>1){a[i]*=$i;} #make the product computation for all lines greater than 1
        else{a[i]=$i} #initialize the array on the first line
    if(NR%3==0){ #every 3 lines 
        printf $1 OFS $2 OFS; #print the first 3 fields
        for(i in a){ #then loop on the array and print cell and computed product
            printf $(i-1) OFS a[i] OFS;
            a[i]=1} #reset all elements of the array to 1
        printf ORS;} #print EOL
}
```